# Find Orphaned Folders using CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to create an SQL Syntax to search my database for folders on the network that users can't access.

Let me explain:

My Database has 5 tables:

Table: Folders

- FUID - INT - Unique ID
- Path - Varchar - Example: E:\shared
- STATUS - INT - 1 = good, 0 = stale

Table: Groups

- GRUID - INT - Unique ID
- Class - varchar - User or Admin Group (admin group being a sysadmin group)
- Name - Example HR_Users
- STATUS - INT - 1 = good, 0 = stale

Table: Users:

- URUID - INT - Unique ID
- Class - varchar - Standard User or Admin User (admin user being a sysadmin)
- Name - Varchar - Example: Smith, John
- STATUS - INT - 1 = good, 0 = stale

Table: UG_JOIN:

- UID: Unique ID
- GRUID - INT - Relationship to Groups
- URUID - INT - Relationship to Users
- STATUS - INT - 1 = good, 0 = stale

Table: ACLS:

- UID - INT - Unique ID
- FUID - INT - Relationship to Folders FUID
- GRUID - INT - Relationship to Group GRUID
- URUID - INT - Relationship to User URUID
- ACCESS - VARCHAR - Type of Access, list, read, modify, full control
- STATUS - INT - 1 = good, 0 = stale

The reason I have to have both the users and groups in the ACL table is because some users are directly assigned permissions at the folder, not by group.

Anyway, What I am trying to find out is:

- What folders don't have any permissions for standard users
- Including the above, I want to be able to filter out by ACCESS, so search for folders where Standard Users don't have Modify Access).
- Also want to filter out stale groups, users, UG_Join, folders and acls using the STATUS Column

I'm NOT trying to find what certain users have access to. I don't care about that, what I want is what folders standard users cant access (list, read, modify, full control). I don't expect to see usernames or group names in my result, just paths.

Logically all I can come up with is get all the paths that Admins have access to (which is 100% of the paths) then skip paths that end-users have access two, leaving only paths that only Admins have access to. Any idea on how I would go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query below. It gets all the folders, and then uses all standard users and any standard groups of that user before applying to filter to only show the folders without a standard user or a standard user in a standard group assigned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    F.Path
FROM Folders F
    INNER JOIN ACLS A
        ON A.FUID = F.FUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            U.URUID,
            G.GRUID
        FROM Users U
            LEFT OUTER JOIN UG_JOIN UG
                ON UG.URUID = U.URUID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups G
                ON G.GRUID = UG.GRUID
                    AND G.Class = 'User' -- Whatever class needs to be user group
        WHERE U.Class = 'Standard User' -- Whatever class neeed to be standard group
            -- AND U.STATUS = 1 -- If you only care about active users
    ) UG
    ON (A.URUID = UG.URUID OR A.GRUID = UG.URUID)
WHERE UG.URUID IS NULL
```

Comment: This query might just work if it didn't return the stale permissions / folders / users / groups. This is a great start though. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you. Sorry for confusion. I assumed from your question you were refreshing the permissions in your database through some script based on the table structure. Are you asking for a powershell script to read actual ACL and traverse your folders?

Comment: No I have a powershell script that reads the actual ACLs of each folder and places the raw values into the database. The script also query's active directory for all the users and group members. I already have it setup to auto refresh the data every two weeks. With this being said, I really just want an SQL query that can tell me which folders on our file share users aren't able to access (Read/List) (1), and another query to see what folders users can't Modify / Write to  (2)

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to combine first and second requirement, so i use Or operator at below, lets me know if i misunderstand u :)

```
DECLARE @Class NVARCHAR(100) = 'STANDARD USER'
DECLARE @Access NVARCHAR(100) = 'Modify'



SELECT F.[PATH]
    FROM Folders F
    INNER JOIN ACLS A
        ON A.FUID = F.FUID
    INNER JOIN Users U
        ON U.URUID = A.URUID
    INNER JOIN Groups G
        ON G.GRUID = A.GRUID
    INNER JOIN UG_JOIN UG
        ON UG.URUID = U.URUID
    INNER JOIN UG_JOIN UG2
        ON UG2.GRUID = G.GRUID      
    WHERE (U.Class != @Class --First requirement : What Folders dont have any permission for standard user
                           -- means i will filter out standuser
     OR (A.Access Not LIKE '%' + @Access + '%' 
        AND U.Class = @Class)-- second requirement: search for folders where standard users dont have modify access
     )
    AND F.Status != 0 --Third reqirement : also want to filter out stale group for all the table
    AND A.Status != 0
    AND U.Status != 0
    AND G.Status != 0
    AND UG.Status != 0
    AND UG2.Status != 0
```

Comment: Requirement 1 & 2 are two separate querys. I am so sorry for the confusion.